# Adding tabs to tabcontrol from inside a tab

Tags: wpf, mvvm, .net-4.0

Well, I have been scratching my head for some time now. But failed to find solution to my problem. What I have is a MainViewModel with and ObservableCollection TabItems. The MainViewModel is set as DataContext for the MainView (User Control) which in turn hosts the TabControl. The tabcontrol is bound to TabItems collection. The Content of the tabcontrol will be ReportItems User Control.

This setup is basically for report for reporting UI for SSRS. The first tab contains a list of Reports selecting which would show a few listboxes from where the user would select the Report Parameters. Not after selecting parameters, the user click a button which in turn generates a report and adds a tab to the tab control with the reporthost.

The reason I am trying to select the report from a tab and not the Main View is that there are a lot of parameters to be selected and if I add the listboxes to the MainView, the space left for the tabcontrol would be less and the user would need to scroll down to view the reports.

I am not sure if my design is flawed but I wanted to figure out a way to add the new ReportItemViewModel to be added to the TabItem collection. That means allowing a child tab to add a sibling by sending a ReportItemViewModel object to MainViewModel and add to the colection.

I thought of using a static Collection to do so but that would not call my OnPropertyChange method. Also, having a static method in the MainViewModel does not help as it would not be able to add the object to the collection since the collection is not static.

I am not posting any code here since I am stuck at how to begin itself. I looked at another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064365/adding-tabs-to-tabcontrol-from-inside-usercontrol) but could not figure out how to use it.

Sorry for long description, Just wanted to make the question clear.

I am open to any suggestion, also if I can get a better design. I am desperate and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could use a popup or an expander to host the UI for the adding process. that way you don't use screen real estate and you don't write adding logic in yout ReportItemViewModel.

Comment: Popup was something that I had thought about but I felt as if it would look out of place. About expander, well not sure how to implement it as I have multiple reports. Do you mean that for each report I have one expander in disabled/invisible mode and should be made enabled/visible based on report selection. Can you elaborate?

Comment: You said you had your lists in a tab and not in the Main View because you want to preserve screen real-estate. I was saying that using an expander in your main view could provide you with enough room for the reports when collapsed, and then with enough room to add new reports when expanded.

Comment: well, what I understand is that your suggestion is to put the parameters list in main view and the tabcontrol, with reports in tabs, in expander? If this is your suggestion, it looks feasible but I am not sure about the look and feel it would give to the app. Still, will try, as I have no more ideas except these 2 now.

Comment: my other suggestion would be exactly what Rachel recommended in her answer. It seems that you need to find a way to communicate between your ViewModels (ReportItemViewModel and MainViewModel). You create the item in the ReportItemViewModel and send a message to MainViewModel with the newly added item to be added in the collection. I successfully used an Event Aggregator pattern to achieve this in the past.

Comment: Thanks Alex. The Event Aggregator really did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an `ICommand` to your `MainViewModel` for adding a new item to your `ObservableCollection`, and use a `RelativeSource` binding to find the command from within the `TabItem`

So your  MainViewModel would have

```cs
ObservableCollection<IViewModel> TabItems
IViewModel SelectedTabItem
ICommand AddTabCommand
```

where `AddTabCommand` basically does

```cs
void AddTab(IViewModel newItem)
{
    TabItems.Add(newItem);
    SelectedTabItem = newItem;
}
```

and your UI would look something along the lines of this

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SelectReportViewModel}">
    <Grid>
        ...
        <!-- Use the CommandParameter property to pass specified ReportItemViewModel to open -->
        <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.AddTabCommand, 
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" />
        ...
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding TabItems}" />
```

Another alternative is to use some kind of event system, such as MVVM Light's `Messenger` or Microsoft Prism's `EventAggregator`, to broadcast/subscribe to events.

Your `MainViewModel` would subscribe to `AddTabEvents`, while your `SelectReportViewModel` would broadcast those events anytime a new tab should be added. I have a brief summary on my blog article about [communication between ViewModels](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/06/05/communication-between-viewmodels-with-mvvm/) if you're interested.

Comment: This looks promising. I was actually looking for something like this but never heard of it as I am relatively new to WPF. Never had an idea as to how to communicate from one VM to another. Will implement and let you know how it's going.

Comment: Awesome... It worked... I used the Event Aggregator pattern... Worked like a charm... So many thanks... :)